# JavaFX 8 Edit table cell on click of placeholder button

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In my `TableView` I'm using a button as the placeholder when there are no items available in the table. And on click of this button I want to add a new row and then make the first cell in this row editable. I was able to successfully add new row, but the making the first cell editable does not work. I have tried using Platform.runLater to start the editing, but it doesn't work either. Below is the code for what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class TableEditTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> colA = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        colA.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        colA.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> colB = new TableColumn<>("Age");
        colB.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        colB.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> colC = new TableColumn<>("Gender");
        colC.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gender"));
        colC.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colA, colB, colC);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Add Item");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            tableView.getItems().add(new Person());

            // Edit the first cell
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                tableView.edit(0, colA);
            });
        });

        tableView.setPlaceholder(btn);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```